# How to get a cell value in the gridview row updating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have tried this:

```
GridViewRow row = MedChangeTable.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string med = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "MedicationName").ToString();
```

For some reason the row.DataItem is `null`.

Comment: From MSDN: "The DataItem property is only available during and after the RowDataBound event of a GridView control."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int cellIndex = 1;
GridViewRow row = MedChangeTable.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string med = row.Cells[cellIndex].Text;
```

You better check if you a control inside the cell. Something like this:

```
string med = ((Label)(row.Cells[cellIndex].Controls[0])).Text;
```